# Microsoft Word: Adding ScreenTip changes text to {Hyperlink\| BookmarkName \o"screentip}, but want original text

Tags: ms-word

Microsoft word fails to add hyperlink over bookmark and show Hyperlink text everytime

I select the text.
[image]

Then i add bookmark from Insert -> link -> add
[image]

Then when i add Link (ctrl+K) and go to insert document and screentip by clicking bookmark

[image]

It just show this text instead of original text.

[image]

Can anyone suggest what the issue is actually?

Answer (score 0):

*I think this is off-topic but you have more experience here than I do.*

### Press Alt+F9 to toggle display of field codes / results.

On some computers, this is **Fn+Alt+F9**. On Macs, use Opt instead of Alt.

The original text does not appear in the field code but is there and will show up in the document.

---

I originally missed your real question and the mistaken answer follows below.

### This has nothing to do with the presence or absence of the bookmark.

This is the ordinary behavior of the Hyperlink and the AutoText fields in Word. The text displayed in the document does not appear when you display the field.

This is examined in my article on the Microsoft site about [Pop-Up text in Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/pop-up-text-in-microsoft-word/f070b772-7d8e-4a29-8943-bca01967cb76?tm=1609428405945).

Here is the field insertion dialog box:

[image: screenshot of dialog box]

Here is what it looks like in the document:

[image: screenshot of hyperlink]

And here is the field code shown using Alt+F9:

[image: screenshot of field code]

Note that the display text is not shown at all in the field code. It is still there. If you select the field and enter the following in the Immediate Window of the vba editor you will see the display text.

```
? Selection.Fields(1).Result
```

I suspect this comes from the origination of these two fields. With the hyperlink field, it is often created using selected text. It does not especially make sense, but it is how the field operates.